# Conditional block vs conditional statement (if)

Tags: awk

Say I have a file:

```
PRO 1
GLN 5.55112e-17
ILE -6.245e-17
THR 5.55112e-17
```

I want every line that has a number unequal to 1 in the second column to change it to 0 and keep the rest.

If I use `if` (i.e conditional statement), everything is OK:

```
awk '{if($2!=1){print $1,"0"}else{print $0}}' file
PRO 1
GLN 0
ILE 0
THR 0
```

But when I use the conditional block, something undesired happens:

```
awk '$2!=1 {print $1,"0"} {print $0}' file
PRO 1
GLN 0
GLN 5.55112e-17
ILE 0
ILE -6.245e-17
THR 0
THR 5.55112e-17
```

You can see what's wrong.

- How do I fix this error?
- Why does this error occur?
- What's the different between a conditional statement and a
  conditional block?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In an `if` statement, you have an `else`. If `if` doesn't match, the `else` branch is executed.

In a conditional statement, both actions are executed, regardless of the condition is true or false.

A simple fix:

```
$ awk '$2!=1 {print $1,"0";next};{print $0}' file
PRO 1
GLN 0
ILE 0
THR 0
```

And you can make it more concise:

```
$ awk '$2 != 1 {print $1,"0";next};1' file
PRO 1
GLN 0
ILE 0
THR 0
```

When condition is true `1` and there is no action, `awk` default behavior is `print`. `print` with no argument will print `$0` by default.

Comment: You could also golf it into `awk '$2!=1?$2=0:"";1' file`.

Comment: @terdon: Good golfing. I think it can be difficult to OP to understand that.

Comment: @cuonglm could you please explain the role of `next`. I guess it suppresses the second print if the first one is true. Something like `continue` in `C`.

Comment: @Alexander Cska: `next` suppresses processing current input line, skip to the next one. The same role as `while`, but for the whole `awk` program. Also, `awk` has its own `while`

Answer (score 11):

The second block in

```
awk '$2!=1 {print $1,"0"} {print $0}' file
```

isn't conditional.  It is acted upon for every line, and thus prints every line.

Instead, write:

```
awk '$2!=1 {print $1,"0"} $2==1 {print $0}' file
```

Or write:

```
awk '$2!=1 {print $1,"0"; next} {print $0}' file
```

This will cause the unconditional block to be skipped, if the conditional block is matched.